# Can i open the cookies file and see what's in that file?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I found a cookies file in the location "C:\Users\Agnivesh\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default".
I'm a little curious about the data in it. 
I only see unformatted text when I opened the file in notepad.

Is there a way to open and see the contents of that file?

Comment: The cookies files are just plain text, but the text is most likely encoded to preserve file size and prevent it from being easily read.  You will most likely not be able to de-obfuscate it.

Comment: Why not just look at them in the browser settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight forward way to examine them is to open your developer window as you browse like below

Click F12-> then follow the tabs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Checked with Microsoft Edge: It's an sqlite file, which can be opened easily. e.g this link: https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/
Enjoy!
This will allow you to check out all of your cookies, not just the ones on specific websites.
(Found this out by trying to open with vs code, on the top of the file "SQLite format 3")